# Mod_rewrite rule like facebook have for users

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want that if anyone types

```
www.mysite.com/anna
```

then it will take it to

`www.mysite.com/second.php?user=anna`   (second.php in root directory)

And on this second.php file there is a link to an image present at : www.mysite.com/images/img.jpg

then this image will get displayed too .

**i tried this rule :-**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ second.php?
name=$1 [L]
```

But its not working for me :(

2) the username can only have numbers and alphabat (a-z or A-Z) only ...

3) if there exists an directory then this instead of the rule it show that directory in root.

Can anyone help me?

---

It does not worked for me .... the script you gave me ....

i find a tutorial and write this on by using some of your code :-

```
RewriteEngine On
# if file is not a directory...:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
# ...and if filename doesn't exist:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# ...then we can process:
# 

RewriteRule ^([^/\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ second.php?name=$1 [L]
```

so i am finally left with one problem ....

if i type `mysite.com/hi`
then every thing work fine and second.php show every image and all text but if i usse this 
`mysite.com/hi/` then the images dont show up .

**

> If you Find any problem in my code please edit it , as i really dont
>   know what i have done , only thing is it is working fine for me with
>   all the constraints . Just one problem as i described

**

Comment: do you mean to have your RewriteRule span 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that may be very close to what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if file is not a directory...:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
# ...and if filename doesn't exist:
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# ...then we can process:
# 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /second.php?user=$1 [QSA]
```

Note: maybe you'll want to stop the process, and don't continue rewriterule if it matches. Just add the "Last" = "L" flag at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /second.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Tell me if it works.